# Why Swagger does not show the method with parameter?

Tags: .net, swagger

I have a .NET 6 minimal api application.
When I use method with int type parameter like

```
app.MapGet("/calc/{sum1}", (int sum1) =>
{
    var msg = String.Format($"Hey {sum1}");
    Log.Information("/calc/{0} response: {1}", sum1, msg);
    return msg;
})
.WithName("Calc");
```

then Swagger page shows me this method with parameter and I can try it out.
But if I use method like this

```
app.MapGet("/calc3/{prod1}", (Product prod1, CalcSvc calcSvc) =>
{
    var msg = String.Format($"Hey {prod1}");
    Log.Information("/calc3/{0} response: {1}", prod1, msg);
    return msg;
})
.WithName("Calc3");
```

then Swagger page show the method but does not show parameter.

What is incorrect?

Comment: Have you considered using POST instead of GET?

Comment: This is a GET method. I have no possibility to use it in Swagger UI thats why I use direct query in the browser like http://localhost:72348/calc3/id=111&name=aqswde

Comment: But the question is why I see the MapGet methods with single types (int, string etc) but do not see with the object